# How to add a manual discrete color fill vector ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, ggmap

The default colors are not discrete enough. I need to specify my own color vector. Any ideas on whether it's possible since I have already specified scale_fill_discrete. I could not get scale_fill_manual to work in this case.

Ideally the 2 legends would be combined with the bubble size legend receiving the relevant fill color and having the "Super_Region" name listed next to the bubble and perhaps even the Genetic_Similarity percentage listed next to it, but I realize that maybe a stretch without resorting to adding a table to the map.

My output plot is shown below superimposed on a terrain world map.

```
results <- read.csv("A.csv")
map_K30 <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = c(lon=180.000, lat=36.659), zoom=2, maptype = 'terrain', color = 'color')) + 
  geom_point(data = results, aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = Genetic_Similarity, fill= Super_Region), shape = 21, alpha = .8,) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 15) + scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4)))
```

[image: Output World plot]

Comment: Replace `scale_fill_discrete` with `scale_fill_manual` and set your desired colors via the the `values` argument.

Comment: Thanks but wouldb't I be giving up control on size of the legend color symbols if I did thatt ? (Symbols would get tiny)

Comment: Nop. Of course you could still use `guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4))` with `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: ....+geom_point(data = results, aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = Genetic_Similarity, fill= Super_Region), shape = 21, alpha = .8,) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 15) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "blue","grey", "yellow","orange","purple", "red","black", "violet"), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))+ guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 8))                         I get error: Error in map_K30 <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = c(lon = 180, lat = 36.659),  : 
  could not find function "<-<-"

Comment: Use it as an argument as you have done in scale_fill_discrete, i.e. `scale_fill_manual(values = ..., breaks = ..., guide = ...)`

Comment: Now all the bubbles are grey and no Super_Region legend gets displayed : scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "blue","grey", "yellow","orange","purple", "red","black", "red"), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 8))) + ....

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated